# Python returns nothing after if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some guidance as to why nothing is being printed in the shell after I run the program.
Here is my code:

```
def numbersize1(x):
    """returns the string 'Negative!' if the number is less than zero, 'Small!' if the number is at least zero but less than 10, 'Medium!' if the number is at least 10 but less than 100, and 'Large!' if the number is greater than or equal to 100.

    Number -> str"""
    if x<0:
        return str('Negative!')
    if x==0 and x<10:
        return str('Small!')
    if x==10 and x<100:
        return str('Medium!')
    if x==100 and x>100:
        return str('Large!')
```

As I stated before, when I run the script, nothing appears in the shell. In other words, if I input a '1,' the string 'Small!' should appear, and it doesn't.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you testing if `x==0` if you want to print the message if x is 1?

Comment: you are looking for `print` not `return`

Comment: Your logic is flawed. How can `x` be both 100, and greater than 100?

Comment: @Idgorman it's probably safe to assume that whatever called the function is being printed out with the returned string.

Comment: `x` needs to be an integer but your comment suggests its a string. Add `assert isinstance(x, int)` as a debugging check, or do something like `x = int(x)`.

Comment: To the the people downvoting this question: This may be a beginner mistake, but we all had to start somewhere.

Comment: beginner mistake, guys, thanks for the input

Comment: @JaredBanton If you think any answer has solved your problem, please accept it as a solution. Check  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

If you write this:

```
if x==0 and x<10:
```

You are saying that `x` equals zero *and* it is less than 10. If `x` doesn't equal zero, the `if` won't match.

Similarly all your others. Look at what they say and think about what they are going to do.

You don't have to convert strings to strings, so you could simplify it just to:

```
if x<0:
    return 'Negative!'
if x<10:
    return 'Small!'
if x<100:
    return 'Medium!'
return 'Large!'
```

Answer (score 4):

Your conditionals are all bad

```
if x==0 and x<10:
```

should be

```
if x>0 and x<10:
```

`if x==10 and x<100:` --> `if x>10 and x<100:`

`if x==100 and x>100:` --> `if x>100:`

The best way would be

```
if x<0:
    return ('Negative!')
elif 0<=x<10:
    return ('Small!')
elif 10<=x<100:
    return ('Medium!')
elif x>=100:
    return ('Large!')
```

Comment: He probably means `0 <= x < 10`, etc, but the lower bound isn't necessary because of the `return`s.

Comment: Actually there is nice syntactic sugar in Python: you can write `0 < x < 10` instead of `x>0 and x<10`.

Comment: Why do you convert the strings to `str`? I thought strings already *were* strings…

Comment: @Gandaro Yeah .. Shouldn't have copied the code from OP

Comment: In it's current state, your suggestion would ignore x = 0, 10, or 100.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the incorrect conditions, your program doesn't output anything because you don't tell it to. `return` doesn't output to the console window, it returns a value. Replace all occurances of `return` with `print` for Python-2.x or use the `print()` function for python-3.x